# Visual Studio: Missing assembly reference to "Windows"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run the sample code found here, in C#:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2/sourcecode?fileId=51046&pathId=1435720579

When opened in Microsoft Visual Studio, it is missing a reference to something simply called "Windows". Not "System.Windows", not "WindowsBase", but just simply "Windows".

Searching for NuGet packages within Visual Studio, or online, have proven fruitless, possibly because the result is indistinguishable from anything that mentions "Windows", which is one heck of a bunch of possible references (including, for example, "System.Windows").

The package also needs a couple of WindowsAPICodePack references that I found through NuGet, so they are not the problem. It's just this mysterious "Windows" reference that I'm missing, which is not available from within Visual Studio by "Add reference...", and I can't find online or in NuGet.

Comment: It looks, that this is a project for UWP/WinRT, so you should try to install Windows 10 SDK first

Comment: There is also a reference `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL`, you can install it from nuget and update reference path

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: Yes, I found those through NuGet without trouble, thanks. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: But I'm now installing the UWP/WinRT stuff to see if that works. If you're confident in it working, please post your comment as a response so that I can mark it as correct. Otherwise I'll try it and let you know if it works. :) It'll take a while downloading and installing, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows.dll` is UWP reference, which is required to call [`ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.gettemplatecontent) method in your sample.

You also has `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL` reference, it's available on Nuget, you can install it and update reference path.

`<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>` says that you'll need to install Windows 8.1 SDK or install Windows 10 SDK and upgrade the target platform

Actually, the sample which you are trying to run is outdated and targets VS2012. You can use the newer and modern sample of toast notification from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop)

Comment: Having installed the Windows 10 SDK as per your suggestion, I was able to follow hints by double-clicking the error/warning that complained about the missing reference and determine that I needed to then add references to Windows.Data, Windows.Foundation and Windows.UI. With those added, the project ran as expected, without changing the target platform. After that, I could even remove the seemingly bogus "Windows" reference in the References-folder in the Project explorer. (I already had WindowsAPICodePack by Microsoft so that was never a problem.) Thanks for the help!